# How to unload angularjs modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, module

I have an application that consists of N Modules. Almost all of those modules will be loaded on demand.

Is there any good way to organize AngularJS application with dynamically loaded and unloaded modules?

## Why do we need unload modules

- Number of Modules (N) can be as much as possible and I can't guarantee any maximum number of them. So I try to avoid excessive use of the memory;
- I don't think it is the best practice to leave the code inside browser that we not going to use (I don't like the idea that tab with my webapp will consume all available memory and will hangs the browser);
- I think Google is too going that way. You can work with your Gmail whole the day and it's still running properly (*Google I/O 2013 - A Trip Down Memory Lane with Gmail and DevTools* http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9Jlu_h_Lyw).

## Linked

- [the Nested Modules in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891169/the-nested-modules-in-angularjs)

Comment: In [this](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy) example application I am experimenting on loading Angular views and Angular modules dynamically on demand. Although I am not completely satisfied with it, it works. Have no idea how to *unload* modules though, sorry.

Comment: Eugene, did you find the solution? I totally agree with you that if we can't unload modules in `S P A` then we must have serious doubts about angular advantages!

Comment: I've expressed my understanding this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467908/angularjsrequirejs-and-modules

Answer (score 5):

As of Angular 1.2.16 and 1.3.0 beta, the `bootstrap()` method [defines a specific element on the DOM as the root scope for a collection of modules](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap). There is no corresponding method to unbind. The `ng-app` directive is [just a shortcut for `bootstrap()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp), so the same limitation applies.

The angular-requirejs-seed project Artemis linked to does not answer your question. It uses the `NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!` property to [suspend the bootstrap process and dynamically define which modules to add](https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed/blob/master/app/js/main.js#L22) at the time the page is loaded. It does not unload anything.

**The most straightforward way to overcome Angular’s inherent inability to unload modules is to destroy the DOM element where your modules are running.** Unfortunately, by destroying the element, you also lose whatever markup you had. One solution to that problem is to put your app’s markup into an HTML5 `<template>` element and clone its contents. Here’s [an example I wrote in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zuqem/2/edit?html,js,output) where an ambiguously named `someGuyInASuit` directive loads a picture of Dr. Jekyll or Mr. Hyde depending on which module is loaded.

This work-around is not well suited to an app consisting of many modules, especially if you intend to swap them in and out frequently as the user interacts with it. For one, all your models will be destroyed. Also, all the `config()` and `run()` blocks will be re-run. You may want to either fork Angular and add your own un-bootstrap method or have a look at another framework such as React, which has [a method for unloading components](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.unmountcomponentatnode) built in.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could find this post helpful. http://rarabaolaza.tumblr.com/post/56707155391/a-plugin-based-architecture-for-angularjs-apps

It describes an aproximation to using requirejs and some metadata to create a plugin based angular app where every plugin is a module, maybe you could adapt it to your needs or get some ideas. But no module unloading I´m afraid.

If you believe this could help you I´m currently revising it and (I believe) improving the ideas, so feel free to ask

HTH

Comment: Yes, I'm also going to use RequireJS to extend Angular's modules in this way I think it more suitable for another question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891169/the-nested-modules-in-angularjs

But yes, the question about unloading the modules is still actual. So if you are going to find something, I'd like to hear it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this project. You can use Angular alongside with RequireJs https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed

Regarding your project, I wouldn't care about numerous angular modules, they are just a lightweight objects that allow you to split you code into logical parts.
If you faced some memory problems consider some code refactoring to get rid of performance killers.

Comment: What happens if you need to potentially dynamically load dozens of modules, each with their own set of services, controllers, directives, etc? Depending on the module's components, it may not be so lightweight.