# Is there a vite plugin for angularjs apps that would enable some for of HMR?

Tags: angularjs, vite

We are rewriting an AngularJS app with svelte components and using Vite for building it.

It works great for the svelte components, but changes made to AngularJS code files requires the whole application to reload.

Has anyone solved that problem or and pointers that would help us construct the angularjs app differently in order to achieve that?

We changing pieces of it to Typescript, and import every file required. But the imports are not all referenced. Since AngularJS apps use injection.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. AngularJS module unloading isn't a thing as it was never designed for that.

More information in this similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23000380/4096074